# How to make g++ (avr-g++) output error line number and column?

Tags: debugging, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

i believe -g turn on debug information output:

```
09-19 19:31:34.788: INFO/System.out(24948): /data/data/app/sdk/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -I/data/data/app/sdk/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/data/data/app/sdk/hardware/arduino/variants/standard /data/data/app/build/Blink.cpp -o /data/data/app/build/Blink.cpp.o
09-19 19:31:34.828: WARN/System.err(24948): /data/data/app/sdk/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++[1]: syntax error: ')' unexpected
```

not sure the command-line is build correctly and some arguments can be missed but it's [arduino IDE code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/app/src/processing/app/debug/Compiler.java).

why error line number and column is missing and how can i switch it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** based on comments:

The OP had installed a MacOS `g++` executable on a Linux system. The Linux system didn't recognize it as an executable file, so it tried to execute it as a shell script, resulting in a misleading error message.

---

That particular error message:

```
syntax error: ')' unexpected
```

looks like a shell error, not a compiler error.

On my system, a C++ program with an extraneous `)` causes g++ to produce this message:

```
c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cpp:2:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
c.cpp:2:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

Note that the messages include line and column numbers, as g++ syntax error messages generally do.

whereas a Bourne shell script with an extraneous `)` produces a message like this:

```
./foo.sh: 3: ./foo.sh: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

which is very similar, but not quite identical, to what you saw. (The difference could easily be caused by a different implementation of `sh`.)

Somewhere, either you have a shell script with a syntax error, or you're trying to execute something other than a shell script as if it were a shell script.

What command are you running that produces this error? Is

```
/data/data/app/sdk/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++
```

a proper executable? What happens if you run

```
/data/data/app/sdk/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ --version
```

from the command line?  What about

```
file /data/data/app/sdk/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ ?
```

From a comment, this command:

```
/data/data/app/sdk/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ --version
```

produces the same error message:

```
syntax error: ')' unexpected).
```

Which means that the `avr-g++` command is executable, but not recognized by the system as an executable, so it's trying to run it as a shell script.

What OS are you running this on? Is the `avr-g++` command intended to run on the host system or on the target (running `g++` on an Arduino seems unlikely). Compare the output of

```
file /data/data/app/sdk/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++
```

to, for example,

```
file /usr/bin/g++
```

or, if it's a symbolic link, to whatever actual file it points to (`/usr/bin/g++-4.7` on my system). The point is to determine just what kind of file this `avr-g++` is, and to compare it to executables that are known to be correct for your system. (Just to be 100% sure, try `/usr/bin/g++ --version`.)

On my system, for example, I get:

```
$ file /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++: symbolic link to `g++-4.7'
$ file /usr/bin/g++-4.7
/usr/bin/g++-4.7: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xac398e1061dbb1a6f8da022f0a1616f15cf07085, stripped
```

Comment: Probably your're right - i'm preparing gcc for x86 android device and this can be execution problem. This is linux executable (elf) and i'm going to provide you requested output..

Comment: The same output for '--version' parameter (avr-g++[1]: syntax error: ')' unexpected). What can i do in order to define the reason and fix it?

Comment: @4ntoine: I've updated my answer with some more things to look into.

Comment: The file is cross-compiled for Android x86 device and 'file' output is 'MBA-Anton:bin asmirnov$ file avr-g++
avr-g++: Mach-O executable i386'

Comment: You're absolutely right, i've pushed mac executables instead of linux ones. Thanks a lot! PS. Though error output was misleading..